# Etimologia da palavra encrenca

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica

Vi em alguns lugares, como [nesta página](https://www.dw.com/pt-br/quando-as-palavras-viajam-da-alemanha-para-o-brasil/a-2300234), que encrenca vem de "ein krenke" (algo como um doente ou uma doença em iídiche). No entanto, os dicionários que consultei dizem apenas que encrenca vem do verbo encrencar e que este tem origem obscura.

A tese de que encrenca vem de "ein krenke" é baseada no tráfico de mulheres judias do leste europeu entre aprox. 1860 e 1930, que eram levadas ao Brasil para serem prostitutas. A Wikipédia apresenta o [seguinte resumo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwi_Migdal) sem apresentar fontes explicitamente:

> Por quase um século, mulheres judias nascidas no Leste Europeu e conhecidas como "polacas", que se prostituíram no Brasil, usavam expressões que deram origem a muitas palavras populares no Brasil. Quando suspeitavam que um cliente tinha uma doença venérea, diziam "ein krenke" ("doença", em iídiche), que se transformou em "encrenca".

Se isso for verdade, então essa palavra só deveria aparecer mais tarde em Portugal, já que seria necessário um certo tempo para que brasileiros "criassem" a palavra encrenca e mais tempo para que ela fosse "exportada". Além disso, os dicionários provavelmente estariam errados, já que encrenca vir de "ein kranke" deve implicar que encrencar vem de encrenca e não o contrário.

Alguém tem informações confiáveis sobre a origem da palavra encrenca?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: A origem pelo iídiche é extremamente difundida, mas aparentemente duvidosa e muitas outras origens são propostas, portanto "origem obscura" parece mesmo ser a descrição mais rigorosa.

---

O registro mais antigo de "encrenca" no [Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/) é de Emílio de Meneses, num texto datado de 1911, em que a palavra [é usada](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/download/texto/fs000058pdf.pdf) numa frase que sugere que ela era recente no vocabulário:

> esta encrenca! (Não nos encabule o Jornal por usarmos desta gíria: os maus exemplos pegam).

No mesmo corpus, o exemplo mais antigo de uso no português europeu é de Miguel Torga, já em 1945. Esse intervalo pode indicar que a palavra surgiu no Brasil — como de fato consta no Novo dicionário da língua portuguesa (Lisboa, 1913) de Cândido de Figueiredo ([e-print](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/31552/31552-pdf.pdf)):

> **encrenca** *f. Bras. do N.* Difficuldade, embaraço. Intriga. (De *encrencar*)

O verbete também coloca "encrenca" como derivado de "encrencar", como fazem alguns dicionários contemporâneos, como o [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/encrenca) — que incoerentemente ao mesmo tempo [afirma](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/encrencar/) que "encrencar" é derivado de "encrenca".

Há várias etimologias propostas na literatura. Na resposta à essa questão no Ciberdúvidas [listou-se](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-etimologia-da-palavra-encrenca/21292), sem fontes:

> 1 — Origem obscura.
> 2 — Formado do adjectivo espanhol *enclenque*, que significa «adoentado».
> 3 — Derivado do vocábulo provençal *cranc*, que significa «coxo; decrépito».
> 4 — Derivado do verbo latino *intricare*, que significa «embaraçar, enredar».

E o [Houaiss](https://houaiss.uol.com.br), que declara "encrencar" como derivado de "encrenca", coloca a origem deste último como duvidosa, e remete ao elemento "encrenc-", onde apresenta uma lista de etimologias ainda mais longa:

> antepositivo, do português *encrenca* (sXX), que J.P. Machado e A.G. Cunha consideram de étimo obscuro, remetendo o segundo para o espanhol *enclenque*, admitindo, s.v. encrencar, segundo Francisco Torrinha, um cruzamento do alto-alemão antigo *slink* 'esquerdo' + o latim *clināre* 'fazer pender, inclinar', lembrando que Meyer-Lübke atribui a este cruzamento o francês meridional *clinchá, aclincá*; daí, deriva, por motivos semânticos sobretudo, para o latim *sinīster,tra,trum* 'esquerdo, de mau presságio'; Corominas atém-se ao languedociano *clene*, provençal *cranc* 'coxo, impotente, decrépito', bearnês *encrancat* 'derrengado, que sofre do lumbago' e o francês antigo e dialetal *esclenc* 'esquerdo' (procedente do alto-alemão antigo *slink* 'id.'); o fato é que já se ressaltou que no Brasil, na área catarinense de alta presença da cultura alemã, *encrenca* e também *estroina* são muito usuais e vivos; de qualquer modo, às hipóteses acima falta-lhes história;

Notavelmente, nenhuma dessas duas listas acima inclui o iídiche ou alemão moderno, apesar dessa proposta ser antiga e muito difundida (inclusive é o título de um [documentário](https://sao-paulo.estadao.com.br/blogs/edison-veiga/amaldicoadas/) a respeito das mulheres judias traficadas). E textos mais rigorosos costumam ser cuidadosos ao mencionar a possibilidade. Por exemplo (todas as ênfases nas citações são minhas), o jornalista Oscar Pilagallo, para a [Folha](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/ilustrad/fq2608200615.htm) escreve:

> Encrenca é uma palavra de origem obscura. Uma etimologia **possível** é a expressão iídiche "ein krenk", que significa "um doente".

E as teses de doutorado de [Anelise Fróes da Silva](http://hdl.handle.net/10183/217399) e de [Júlia Calvo](http://www.biblioteca.pucminas.br/teses/CiencSociais_CalvoJ_1.pdf) também são cuidadosas:

> Em qualquer pesquisa virtual sobre as “polacas”,e mesmo na literatura disponível, não faltam referências sobre a origem de palavras que entraram no léxico brasileiro, a partir da presença das prostitutas judias no Rio de Janeiro, especialmente. Uma delas, sobre a qual **ouvi em campo diversas  vezes**, é justamente “encrenca”

> **Atribue-se** a elas a palavra “encrenca”, derivada do iídiche “krank”(doença), que **teria** tornado o sinônimo de doença venérea e, posteriormente ganhado sentido de confusão (Flavio  Limoncic 2005: p. 269)

E a menção mais antiga que encontro a essa possível etimologia é de Gilberto Freyre, em "Ordem e Progresso" (1957):

> Corruptelas como envasamento, sulipa, breque, balduína e **talvez** encrenca, que da boca de rústicos passaram à língua corrente do brasileiro

que tem a incerteza da possibilidade reforçada em sua versão [em inglês](https://books.google.de/books?id=--3n83kHhzoC&lpg=PA134&ots=GEW7AhcuxO&dq=%22encrenca%22%20%22german%22&pg=PA134#v=onepage&q=%22encrenca%22%20%22german%22&f=false):

> terms like *embasamento*, *sulipa* (railroad tie or "sleeper"), *breque* (brake), *balduína* (locomotive) and **perhaps** *encrenca* (difficulty, from German *Kränke* **(?)**)

Portanto, não parece haver sinal de que existam evidências maiores para a proposta de etimologia iídiche para a palavra "encrenca" — ou tampouco para as demais propostas — e temos que nos conformar com *origem duvidosa*.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta detalhada! Entendo que não se pode afirmar com precisão e devemos nos contentar com "origem obscura", mas o fato da palavra ter surgido no Brasil de alguma forma corrobora a hipótese da origem íidiche, certo? Pois se viesse de uma palavra espanhola ou do latim, não vejo razão para não ter aparecido em Portugal antes...

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira Sim, é como vejo também. O corpus que usei não é muito extenso e só me baseei em 1 dicionário para "confirmar" a origem brasileira - verificar outros dicionários da época e um corpus maior reforçariam esse indício - mas o ideal, claro, seria encontrar uma evidência ou fonte direta da origem iídiche.